Boundary Values for Ordinary Differential Equations
If I have a second order Ordinary Differential Equation, I would use the normal methods to find the general solution and then apply the boundary conditions, which would be $x(t_0)=x_0$ and $x(t_1)=x_1$ if the equation is defined on a time interval of $[t_0,t_1]$. My question is, what if the time interval is infinite, and I know the value of $x(t)$ at two specific times, is this still a boundary value problem? Because these points specificy the exact form of the solution function, but they don't form "boundaries". If the ODE is third order or higher, these points also don't form any boundary, even if the time interval is finite, as we will need more points to specify the equation. Is this still a Boundary Value problem? What is the exact definition of this type of Differential Equation?

Yes, that still counts as BVP. Also problems where more conditions are possible and they are posed at more than 2 points. The possibility that no solution exists "increases" with the number of nodes where conditions are posed. // The boundary condition can also be any expression involving both value and derivative at this point.
